# Bukkit/Spigot) Getting configure section many times will occur an error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

so recently I'm making some stuff with configure sections, this is my code

```
ConfigurationSection sec = getConfig().getConfigurationSection(p.getWorld().getName() + ".rewards");
        if (sec == null) {
            return;
        }
        int prizessize = sec.getKeys(false).size();
        int random = getRandomInt(0, prizessize);
```

This is my config:

```
     world:
      rewards:
        '0':
          reward-name: '&etest'
          reward-chance: 10
          reward-rarity: '&6Legendary'
          item-type: customhead
          head-name: test
          custom-head-id: eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvZjNkNWU0M2RlNWQ0MTc3YzRiYWYyZjQ0MTYxNTU0NDczYTNiMGJlNTQzMDk5OGI1ZmNkODI2YWY5NDNhZmUzIn19fQ
          reward-item-id: 1
          reward-item-damage: 0
          firework:
            type: BALL
            flicker: true
            trail: false
            colors:
            - BLUE
            fade:
            - WHITE
          commands:
          - say %player% test reward
        '1':
.
.
.
```

So it works fine while doing the reward event for several times but sometimes it spams an error in the console.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getConfigurationSection(MemorySection.java:679) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.get(MemorySection.java:219) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getConfigurationSection(MemorySection.java:679) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getDefaultSection(MemorySection.java:155) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getKeys(MemorySection.java:76) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.createPath(MemorySection.java:780) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.mapChildrenKeys(MemorySection.java:713) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.mapChildrenKeys(MemorySection.java:717) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.mapChildrenKeys(MemorySection.java:717) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getKeys(MemorySection.java:83) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.configuration.MemorySection.getKeys(MemorySection.java:79) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
```

Comment: Updated new error found..

Comment: A StackOverflowError occurs when your memory is exhausted; would you mind providing where/how the given code is called? (via command, in a loop...)

Comment: Its on a runnable for example int time x = 10 if time == 0; cancel the runnable task give reward.

Comment: The error makes sense then, as you are simply overloading the memory; try to define the section outside of the runnable, and only access what you need instead of creating a new object every run.

Comment: Alright is it fine to loop into the configure section on enabling the plugin then save all configuration sections size in a hashmap?

Comment: Not sure if that's a good idea, as they still need to be updated when entries are added / removed - consider creating a final instance of your config for general use.

Comment: Nope still don't work code: https://pastebin.com/6qpkRqt9 it gets a random int from the config section if it didnt found the int it do the reward code again

Comment: Within the code you never initialized `FileConfiguration`, only defined it; if it's your main class (class extending JavaPlugin) use `getConfig()` to access it, and in case it's a different class pass the config as parameter in the constructor.

Comment: i did define it on enable, config = getConfig, also the getconfig is not working too

Comment: From what class are you trying to call it?

Comment: From the main class.

Comment: Then you should be able to call it using `getConfig()`. Please provide your full code, as it might prove difficult to help otherwise.

Comment: Can i contact you on skype or discord that would be a lot easier

Comment: Sorry, I am not at home at the moment and don't have access to those. We should move this comment chain to a chat though.

Comment: There are some hashmaps like size will save the configuresection size of player world, and used is also a hashmap

Comment: I'd recommend saving `getConfig` into a variable instead of calling it each time. You can also specify the segment you need using `getConfig().getConfigurationSection("...")`

Comment: You mean like the code i did provide lately? Fileconfiguration config .. ?

Comment: Got new error https://pastebin.com/brB8jsnG

Answer (score 0):

i was getting a random chance and check if the reward chance is below my chance but there were no chances below my chance so it had endless loop